# SQL Cannot get WHERE EXISTS Clause to work properly and only return rows that have a type for a client within a certain date

Tags: sql, where-clause, exists

OK, this is driving me crazy and the solution I am sure will be pretty simple and I will probably bang my head into a wall. I have a query where I have client data. On some queries I ONLY want clients between a certain date that have had a client visit at some point within that date range, which correspond to Call_Report_ID's 3, 8 or 12. For these clients, I want it to bring back ALL data within the date range, not just the rows with this client visit code. For the other clients who DON'T have a client visit, I want to exclude them from the data.

Here is what I have been playing around with and cannot get it working at all.

```
SELECT * 
FROM CV.Data AS CV 
WHERE EXISTS (SELECT * 
              FROM CV.Data AS CVD 
              WHERE CVD.Call_Report_ID IN(3,8,12) 
                  AND CVD.User_ID = 33) 
    AND CV.User_ID = 33 
    AND CV.Activity_Date BETWEEN '10/1/2018' AND '3/31/2019'
```

So here is an example of What I want:

```
Cust_ID Call_Report_ID Activity_Date
  5         3            10/15/2018
  5         7            10/28/2018
  6         9            10/21/2018
  6         11           10/25/2018
```

In the above when I run this query, I want it to return both rows from Customer 5 since they have a call report ID of 3,8, or 12 in ANY row within the date range, and exclude both rows from Customer 6 since they do not have a call_report_Id with those types in a date range

However, every time I run it, it returns all rows for this user, not just the ones specified in the WHERE EXISTS SubQuery.

What am I dong wrong here?

Comment: First of all, always indent you SQL. You will gain in brain performance.

Comment: Sorry, fixed, it is indented on the server, just not when I pasted it

Comment: Why not join the table on itself instead of your sub-query ? Can you give some data samples for testing on db fiddle.

Comment: @ArnaudPeralta - That would result in the rows being multiplied by the number of matching report ids.

Comment: You almost certainly want to be correlating the subquery with the outer query on some of the other columns - `Cust_ID` for one, possibly others.  Also - don't use `BETWEEN` with dates (especially if the data is in a timestamp) - always use an exclusive upper bound: `AND CV.Activity_Date >= '20181001' AND CV.Activity_Date < '20190401'`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You didn't join subquery with outer query in any way.

```
SELECT * 
FROM CV.Data AS CV 
WHERE EXISTS (SELECT * 
              FROM CV.Data AS CVD 
              WHERE CVD.Call_Report_ID IN(3,8,12) 
                  AND CVD.User_ID = 33
                  AND CV.Cust_ID = CVD.Cust_ID) <--
    AND CV.User_ID = 33 
    AND CV.Activity_Date BETWEEN '10/1/2018' AND '3/31/2019'
```

Answer (score 1):

Replacing `Exist` with `in`:

```
SELECT * 
FROM Data AS CV 
WHERE Cust_ID in (SELECT Cust_ID 
              FROM Data AS CVD 
              WHERE CVD.Call_Report_ID IN(3,8,12) 
                  AND CVD.User_ID = 33) 
    AND CV.User_ID = 33 
    AND CV.Activity_Date BETWEEN '10/1/2018' AND '3/31/2019'
```

Answer (score 0):

How about this:

```
SELECT * 
FROM CV.Data AS CV 
WHERE EXISTS (SELECT * 
          FROM CV.Data AS CVD 
          WHERE CVD.Call_Report_ID IN(3,8,12) 
              AND CVD.User_ID = 33) 
AND CV.User_ID = 33 
AND CV.Activity_Date BETWEEN '10/1/2018' AND '3/31/2019'
AND CV.Call_Report_ID IN(3,8,12)
```

If I were you, I would think why do I need this EXISTS condition, it is indeed not a straight forward filter, however I have not enough information from you to simply discard it.

You may consider my answer as a working hint, but think why do you need this EXISTS condition. It looks like it is not needed and the query could look as follows:

```
SELECT * 
FROM CV.Data AS CV 
WHERE CV.User_ID = 33 
AND CV.Activity_Date BETWEEN '10/1/2018' AND '3/31/2019'
AND CV.Call_Report_ID IN(3,8,12)
```

Comment: The OP wants all `Call_Report_ID`s.  If this query worked, then the subquery is completely superfluous.

Comment: @MattE - This answer doesn't actually fulfill your question, as I understand it.

Comment: @Clockwork-Muse Ack...I was too excited...you are right it only is bringing back the rows with those ID's not all rows that have ANY row with those call report ID's

Comment: @Bartosz, this doesn't work...it only brings back rows with that Call report ID...I want ALL rows that have ANY row for this Customer having a Call Report ID of this type

Answer (score 0):

> it returns all rows for this user, not just the ones specified in the
>   WHERE EXISTS SubQuery

This `EXISTS` does not filter the data returned by the query. 
It returns `TRUE` or `FALSE`. 
So if it returns `FALSE` there will be **no rows** returned by your query 
and if it returns `TRUE` **all the rows** under the conditions of:

```
CV.User_ID = 33 AND CV.Activity_Date BETWEEN '10/1/2018' AND '3/31/2019'
```

will be returned

Comment: Well, yes, but this is rather unspecific as to what could be done to fix the issue.

Comment: *not just the ones specified in the WHERE EXISTS SubQuery* this is the problem. The OP thinks that that EXISTS filters the rows but it does not. How the rows should be filtered? This is for the OP to decide.

Answer (score 0):

It returns all rows because your are not doing any filtering in the exists query.

I think it would be better to change this query, so you would use a join.

Comment: A join would cause the rows to be multiplied by the number of matching report ids.